# How to use Siteminder SSO and Angularjs together?

Tags: angularjs, siteminder

I have to use SiteMinder SSO on the top of my angular application. When user hit given url then route to siteMinder login page. Once login is successfully then I have to take care for all the routes, header and session. I didn't find any relevant resource for anguarjs. Could anyone please help me on this? Do I need to write rest api for this? or there is any magic provided by siteMinder which I can use directly.

```
 @app.route("/", methods =["GET"])
 @app.route("/<bucket_name>", methods =["GET"])
 def auth(bucket_name=None):
   headers = request.headers
   hdr =  dict(headers)
   hdr['bucket'] = bucket_name
   return jsonify(hdr)
```

This python script where request.headers simply gives me whole sso header response (like user name, session, cookie and many more) if I am login and my url is register with sso. That means I am already getting authentication header before calling any rest api and it's binding automatically in my every rest api request right? How can I grab that in anguarjs script?

SiteMinder says SM http header can be accessed through Web Application:

Now questions:

1. Where is good place to access it: client or server side?
2. If from client side then how?
3. If server side then do I need to create separate rest api for this?
4. If in server side then is it okay if I access before my angular app started like this and inject as constant?

```html
function fetchData() {
    var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
    var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

    return $http.get(env.authHeader).then(function(response) {
     flexapp.constant("authHeader", response.data);
     console.log(response);
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        // Handle error case
    });
}
```

5. How do I take care of session?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I looking for same, can we have chat for relevant discussion, or if you already found the solution, please post the answer